# SSRS update a record

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

So we have a SSRS report that displays some information about a product but we will like to update said product. The example I was given goes as follows

| Name | Location | Price | Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Orange | Earth | $100 | Update |

After clicking the Update word ... the price value changes.

| Name | Location | Price | Action |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Orange | Earth | $150 | Update |

Im hoping I can link the word "Update" to a stored proc that we have that will do all the magic.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this but it is not elegant.

I'm assuming you need some way of providing the new price, so that could be a parameter.

Let's take an example where you provide a price increase or decrease as a simple parameter in your report which is going to be passed to a stored proc along with the item selected in order to do the update.

First step is to create a report which looks like the example you provided. Add a parameter to this called say, `pPriceAdjust`. Allow blank values and set blank by default. We need to do this so the report runs initially without a parameter value being set.

Once that report looks OK, leave it to one side for now, we'll come back to that later.

Now create a new report, let's call it `_sub_PriceAdjust`. Add 4 parameters called `pName`, `pLocation`, `pPrice`, `pAdjustment` .

Next add a dataset query that look something like this..

```
UPDATE myTable SET Price = @pPrice + @pAdjustment
    WHERE [Name] = @pName and [Location] = @pLocation

SELECT CONCAT(@pName, ' in location ', @pLocation, ' was updated from ', FORMAT(@pPrice, 'c2'), ' to ', FORMAT(@pPrice + @pAdjustment, 'c2')) as ReturnText
```

You could (and probably should) create a stored proc to do this but for the sake of simplicity it can just go directly in the dataset query.

All we have done is updated the record and then return a message as the dataset query result which can be displayed in the sub report.

Now, add a textbox to your subreport and set it to be the ReturnText field from the dataset. probably something like `=FIRST(Fields!ReturnText.Value, "myDataSetName")` . Make sur ethe text box is big enough to fit the whole message in.

Finally, for this subreport, add another textbox, maybe format it to look like a button, and set it action to Go To Report and choose your original report as the target, this will allow the user to click a button to get back to the original report (*although the report toolbar back button might be better*)

Nearly there....

Go back to the original report and in your "Update" textbox, go to properties and set the Action to Go To Report. Choose the `_sub_PriceAdjust` report and then add each of the 4 parameters and set their values, the first three will be the Field values from the main data set which you should be able to choose from a drop down, the final parameter (pAdjustment) will be the `pPriceAdjust` parameter we setup right at the start of this. There is no reason the `pPriceAdjust` parameter could not be called `pAdjustment` but I named them differently so you could see how each interacted.

Anyway, that should do it. Not pretty but it should work. There is some obvious error checking to add (is the adjustment value zero or blank for example, but I'll leave that bit to you.

To replicate your example, run the report, type `50` into the parameter and click  "update" on the selected line. This should add 50 to the select price. To decrease the price back to the original amount, change the parameter to `-50` and hit update.

This is completely from memory so might not be perfect but if there is something you can't figure out leave a comment and I'll refine the answer.